# How to make a dynamic DTO without to send a complete Payload in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, dto

I have the `updateProvider(ProviderUpdateDto providerUpdt)` method in my Spring controller, But I do not see the need to send the whole payload of the provider entity, if for example the client can only update the name or other attribute, that is, it is not necessary to send the whole entity if only it is necessary to update a field, this produces a Excessive bandwidth consumption when it is not necessary.

**What is a better practice to send only the fields that are going to be updated and be able to build a DTO dynamically?** and **How would I do if I'm using Spring Boot to build my API?**

Comment: Partial changes may be implemented using `PATCH` HTTP verb/method. You should probably search for materials about it.

Comment: @Antot but how are the data sent with the partial changes? How does the controller receive the information related to the change?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jackson library, it provides the annotation `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` and with this only properties with not null values will be passed to your client.
Check the link http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields for an example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but it is not entirely clear to me. Could you give me a simple example of how this looks? remember that I have it is a simple method of updating that could be any field of the provider entity in this case

Comment: I added a link to a tutorial.

Comment: this would work only for data sent to the front-end though, not the other way around, which is what OP is actually asking

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to have a `DTO` object for field changes which would work for every entity you have. E.g:

```
class EntityUpdateDTO {
    // The class of the object you are updating. Or just use a custom identifier
    private Class<? extends DTO> entityClass;
    // the id of such object
    private Long entityId;
    // the fields you are updating
    private String[] updateFields;
    // the values of those fields...
    private Object[] updateValues;

}
```

Example of a `json` object:

```
{
    entityClass: 'MyEntityDTO',
    entityId: 324123,

    updateFields: [
        'property1',
        'property2'
    ],
    updateValues: [
        'blabla',
        25,

    ]
}
```

Might bring some issues if any of your `updateValues` are complex objects themselves though...

Your API would become `updateProvider(EntityUpdateDTO update);`.

Of course you should leave out the `entityClass` field if you have an update API for each `DTO`, as you'd already know which `class` entity you are working on...

---

Still, unless you are working with **huge** objects I wouldn't worry about bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

There are many technique to improve bandwidth usage

- not pretty print Json
- enable HTTP GZIP compression

However, it is more important to ensure ur API is logically sound, omitting some fields may break the business rules, too fine grain API design will also increase the interface complexity